# Search sheet for multiple criteria

Tags: vba

```
For Each c1 In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 Then

MsgBox "Error in " & c1.Address
Exit Sub ' To step out after first error
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I have this code which searches my sheet for non-hidden cells of colour index 16..

However, I wish to add a third criteria:  `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

So that the message only appears when the 3 criteria are satisfied.

Your thoughts are appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `If c1.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 And c1.Value2 = vbNullString Then`

Comment: BTW there's a typo in your code - in this line you have `cl` instead of `c1`.

Comment: Yes this is working, although I have the unforseen problem due to conditional formatting which appears to change the colour of cells yet retain the original colour index.. I.E some cells should no longer be checked by our code but are still listed as code 24!!! is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `Option Explicit`! This way you prevent mixing up `cl` and `c1` as you did in your code! Also, its best practise to use indentation to make your code easier to read.

You can achieve what you wish by using `Application.Intersect`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindErrors()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Application.Intersect( _
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))

        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 16 Then
            c.Activate
            MsgBox "Error in " & c.Address
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```